# Unable to locate JVM fatal error log file (hs_err_pid.log) after Dataproc Spark Job crash

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

After Apache Spark Executor JVM crash in C++ library I'm unable to locate hs_err_pid.log file, that is specified in the Executor JVM output log. Here's an example of Executor output log:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6326dce8b0, pid=28580, tid=0x00007f630ea57700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b01) (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b01-1~deb9u1-b01)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libessence-jni.so+0x18b0]  Java_com_evernote_service_nts_indexer_lib_Essence_EssProcess+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1559573462307_0002/container_1559573462307_0002_01_000005/hs_err_pid28580.log
10:50:00:[32m562[m [Executor task launch worker for task 41] [32mINFO[m  .....NtsLibInternalIndexerProcessor(NtsLibInternalIndexerProcessor.java:50) [32mprocess             [m     Process for user: 18432
[thread 140063422109440 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

But when I'm SSH to target worker machine to locate `hs_err_pid28580.log` I can't find any traces of this file. I've tried:

```
vglazkov@reindex-cluster-vg-w-0:~$ sudo find / -name hs_err_pid28580.log
vglazkov@reindex-cluster-vg-w-0:~$
```

```
vglazkov@reindex-cluster-vg-w-0:~$ sudo ls -la /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/
total 12
drwx--x--- 3 yarn yarn 4096 Jun  4 10:46 .
drwxr-x--- 4 yarn yarn 4096 May 15 15:47 ..
drwx--x--- 3 yarn yarn 4096 Jun  4 10:48 application_1557935076075_0097
```

But in the last case directory named `application_1557935076075_0097` does not match my applicationId `application_1559573462307_0002` and does not contain any `hs_err_pid.log` files